# Dynamically create devices on IoT Central from Node-Red

Tags: node.js, azure, node-red, azure-iot-central

Our company has developed an extensive line of 900mhz wireless sensors for industrial applications.  We also have a gateway device the sensors connect to which is intended to forward data from the sensors to cloud services.  This gateway device connects to the internet via Ethernet/WiFi/Cellular, it is a Linux based device and comes with Node-Red pre installed.

For most of the cloud platforms we use we are able to create a Node-Red flow on the Gateway where the user can enter credentials for their cloud platform account.  Through these credentials devices are provisioned to their account and telemetry can be reported.  In the case of Azure IoT Central however I am having difficulty understanding how this can be accomplished.  I have been through many spider webs back and forth through Microsoft Docs on DTDL, PnP, IoT Central, IoT Hub, etc.  I'm just looking for a starting point of how this could be accomplished.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Node-Red is a flow-based development tool for visual programming. It is mostly known as a programming environment for controlling events.

To solve the issue you are facing you can use this Node-RED module called [node-red-contrib-azure-iot-device](https://github.com/iotblackbelt/node-red-contrib-azure-iot-device), which turns your Node-RED into a full Azure IoT device.

It enable you to deploy the **Azure IoT Device Node-RED** node, which can be used to connect Node-RED to the Azure IoT platform.

> **It can connect to Azure IoT Hub, Azure IoT Central, and use Azure IoT Edge as a transparent gateway.**

Only by following the three simple steps you will be able to set and use this module.

1. [Deploy](https://github.com/iotblackbelt/node-red-contrib-azure-iot-device/blob/master/DEPLOY.md) the Azure IoT Device Node.

   You can install it using the following npm command.

   ```sh
   npm install node-red-contrib-azure-iot-device
   ```
2. [Configure](https://github.com/iotblackbelt/node-red-contrib-azure-iot-device/blob/master/CONFIGURE.md) the Azure IoT Device Node.
3. And finally [use](https://github.com/iotblackbelt/node-red-contrib-azure-iot-device/blob/master/USE.md#use-the-azure-iot-device-node) the Azure IoT Device Node.

For more information read this [Turn Node-RED into a first-class citizen Azure IoT connected device](https://sandervandevelde.wordpress.com/2020/08/31/turn-node-red-into-a-first-class-citizen-azure-iot-connected-device/) document.